# Use a VPN/... only for a specific port on windows?

Tags: networking, vpn, remote, window

I would like to know if there is a way to use another a software to redirect only some ports to another site?

In my case I would like that the port 80(web) goes through a connection, and the other still use my local network.

Comment: Depending on the type of VPN. However if you create a VPN connection in windows under the advanced options you can untick 'use remote gateway' this means it will only use the remote gateway for traffic that is on that IP range and everything else will go via your local connection.

Comment: @CharlesH I don't have yet installed the VPN server on the other side, so it's quite open, could be VPN, openVpn, or any other software which allows me to make a tunnel. I see what you mean with the IP, the goal is to have the VPN for web traffic only, as there IP which are on the two sides

Comment: So you want to basically mask your IP for web browsing by pushing all HTTP and HTTPS traffic down the VPN. There isn't any specific way I know of with a VPN you might want to instead look at setting up a VPN then a proxy with you can put in your internet options which would make the appearance you are browsing from that IP address. Alternative to this would be setup a virtual machine on your main machine connect that to the VPN and use that for web browsing leaving your main machine free for any other outbound traffic.